# Transfer emails between two of Gmail's special accounts

Tags: gmail, google-account

I am lecturer in a university. My university uses free Gmail service. I had changed my email ID and the older one would be closed after a few months.

I don't see Accounts and Import tab, I just see Accounts tab in which no option
is mentioned for importing emails. I tried the method with creating a filter for forwarding, but that too, doesn't work any more in Gmail.

Is there any other method than above for transferring emails from my older account to newer account?

Comment: You don't see an accounts import option because Google doesn't have one.  Setup both accounts using IMAP using an email client of your choice and manually copy the emails to the new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out
I first downloaded all the Emails from my previous account
in MS outlook, then used
Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Outlook

and it worked like a charm thanks for useful information guys

Answer (score 5):

You can set up an email client with your 2 accounts, using IMAP. You can then drag emails between different accounts. This method is **not supported by Google** and transferring large amount of emails will lock up your email client. The trick is to move small portions of your emails at a time.

If you have access to the Google Apps Sync client (the general non-paying public has no access, but Google Apps users usually do), you can download all email from 1 account into a pst file. When done, use Google Apps Migration tool to transfer the contents of the pst file into your new Gmail account.

The method using IMAP is the best method, but it takes the most time and manual effort.

Comment: [**imapsync**](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) could also be used like shown in [this](http://grossi.io/2013/migrating-emails-using-imap-imapsync-tofrom-gmail-yahoo-etc/) article. [**OfflineImap**](http://offlineimap.org/) could also be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try any client like [Beyond Inbox](http://www.beyondinbox.com/) which provide the facility to copy emails between 2 gmail accounts.

For More details :

[How to copy emails between gmail accounts](http://www.beyondinbox.com/documentation/mail-backup--how-to-copy-move-emails-in-imap-account.html)

[How to add Gmail account in Beyond Inbox](http://www.beyondinbox.com/documentation/mail-backup--how-to-configure-imap-account.html)

Comment: its not free ...

Answer (score 0):

Under Setting, Accounts and Import, there is an option to Grant Access to Your Account. In your new account (in the same tab), you then Import Mail and Contacts.

Comment: plz read my post again

Comment: @UsmanWaheed Strange, it's available on my computer. Talk to the IT support and they should be able to help you get the messages into your new account.